# Has any one used HAProxy Enterprise edition - HAPEE ? If so how do you order it - there is not pricing info on their website

Tags: haproxy

Has any one used HAProxy Enterprise edition - HAPEE ? If so how do you order it - there is not pricing info on their website.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Simply send a mail to contact@haproxy.com or info@haproxy.com and ask the required information, as mentionned on HAPEE's page:
http://haproxy.com/products/haproxy-enterprise-edition/

Baptiste